# Youtube-dl Merging Multiple Conditions

Tags: youtube-dl

How can I specify two conditions to be placed on a one video to be downloaded?

i.e. Merging the two conditions stated below.

```
-f bestvideo[height=720]

-f bestvideo[ext=webm]
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `-f bestvideo[height=720][ext=webm]` will download the format in the webm format that has a height of 720 px. This is explained in the [README](https://github.com/rg3/youtube-dl/blob/master/README.md#format-selection).